# Skipping "nodetool upgradesstables" for time series ttl expiry data in Cassandra upgrade from 2.1 to 3.11

Tags: cassandra, upgrade

In Cassandra 2.1 cluster, data format is ka and post upgrade to Cassandra 3.11, I see the new sstables are written in md format. For the time-series data that is going to be expired in 3 months time, can I skip running the nodetool upgradesstables?

I validated the data reads are working fine from the older ka format sstables after upgrade. The reason I want to skip the upgrade is from other threads, I know it is going to take a lot of time for format conversion and anyway this data is going to expire in 3 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's mandatory to run `nodetool sstablesupgrade`, Cassandra 3 will be able to work with old SSTables, but you lose a lot of advantages of Cassandra 3 (for instance, space consumption is significantly reduced). Also [Datastax has a warning in their upgrade documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/upgrade/doc/upgrade/datastax_enterprise/upgrdCstarToDSE.html):

> WARNING: Failure to upgrade SSTables when required results in a significant performance impact and increased disk usage and possible data loss. Upgrading is not complete until the SSTables are upgraded.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Valentina. We have validated and decided on strategy of not running upgrade sstables for large time series data.

Comment: There is no need to upgrade to 2.2. Cassandra supports upgrade from 2.1 to 3.x directly.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Cassandra upgrade is supported from Cassandra 2.1 versions greater or equal to 2.1.9. Will update my answer.